# Spring implicit HTTP OPTIONS method returning wrong "Allow" response headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jax-rs, cxf

I'm using Spring 4.3.3 which has [built-in support for HTTP HEAD and OPTIONS](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-head-options). I've defined my REST API to support only GET method but the implicit OPTIONS method returns other HTTP methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, HEAD.

When I invoke the API using the POST method, I get the HTTP 405 error as expected. Why is the Spring implicit OPTIONS method returning the wrong "Allow" response headers?

My REST service:

```
@Service
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("/test")
public class TestJaxrs {
  @GET  
  @Path("/testJaxrs")
  public String test() {
    return "test ok";
  }
}
```

Actual response header:

```
Allow: POST, GET, OPTIONS, HEAD
```

I'm expecting the response header to be:

```
Allow: GET
```

Comment: You try to call "/test/testJaxrs" by using POST ?

Comment: Why you are using JAX-RS API while you have Spring RestController & GetMapping annotations etc?

Comment: @TinyOS, yes, the POST method on the /test/testJaxrs URL returns HTTP 405

Comment: @GauravSrivastav for the TestJaxrs class, I'm only using JAX-RS annotations and no Spring annotations apart from Service. The Service annotation is required by CXF JAX-RS for component scan.